# FCM com registro do token no Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase

Olá, estou com duvidas sobre o uso do FCM. Estou armazenando o token gerado no app pelo fcm no próprio database do fire, para poder enviar as mensagens de um webService também ligado ao fire, mas para poder enviar essas mensagens é preciso ter uma referencia do token salvo na conta do usuário, minha duvida é: como referenciar o token do app com o ID do usuário que é sua chave principal no BD, como fazer para saber que o email ou nome do usuario que estou colocando no BD é referente a certo ID. 
Por exemplo, no site eu teria a listagem dos emails de todos os usuarios, selecionando um eu encaminharia uma notificação para o dispositivo desse usuario.

Comment: Então você tem que guardar o token junto com o email.

Comment: eu estou cadastrando os dois juntos, dentro de um nó de usuarios, mas na hora de fazer esse "Select" na parte web eu teria que passar o uID do usuario que é gerado pelo proprio fire... Pra ai pegar os email e saber qual o id correto ???

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas daria pra regatar o token através do uid ou do email. Qual sua dificuldade?

Comment: Eu não estou conseguindo entender como montar essa estrutura, quando for puxar no Site, como eu iria referenciar para o usuário o email com o token especifico.